# Output the last instance of failure status from historical data in Bigquery

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I am still on the ropes with BigQuery and I hope you can help me.

I have a data set of failure status from different users in the past 2 months, the scans are done once per day.

Basically, my data set looks like this:

```
WITH failure_table AS
  (SELECT 'Andrea' AS name, 'Failure' AS status, '2022-04-28 4:00:00' AS timestamp
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Karl', 'Failure', '2022-04-28 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-04-27 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Karl', 'Failure', '2022-04-27 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-04-26 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-04-25 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-03-30 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-03-29 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-03-28 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Karl', 'Failure', '2022-03-28 4:00:00')
```

What I wanted to output is the timestamp in which a user first committed a failure, and consecutively commits a failure status every day, leading up to today (2022-04-29).

So in this case, both Andrea and Karl's failures from March will not be considered for analysis, since after March 30, they had success marks and got a failure again only in late April. (I'm not sure if I'm making sense, do let me know).

So my expected output is,

| name | status | started failing timestamp | days failing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andrea | Failure | 2022-04-25 4:00:00 | 4 |
| Karl | Failure | 2022-04-27 4:00:00 | 2 |

I hope someone can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select name, status,  
  min(timestamp) as started_failing_timestamp,
  date_diff(max(date(timestamp)), min(date(timestamp)), day) + 1 as days_failing
from (
  select * except(flag), flag, countif(flag > 1) over(partition by name order by timestamp) grp
  from (
    select *, date_diff(date(timestamp), lag(date(timestamp)) over(partition by name order by timestamp), day) flag
    from failure_table
    where status = 'Failure'
  )
)
group by name, status, grp
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by name order by grp desc)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly! I still need to wrap my head around the logic behind the code, but thank you this definitely helps! :)